# How to measure the Test Fragment response time in jMeter?

Tags: jmeter, response, response-time

My jMeter script performs visiting the Workout history page of the website.
 While leading there the app sends 8 api requests. We put them into one Test Fragment but while running scripts in jMeter I get the response time of each HTTP Request.
 Is there any possibility to get the response time of the whole Test Fragment?

[My Test Fragment screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMiSn.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple. You just add a `Transaction Controller` in the Test Fragment. Move all the HTTP requests under the `Transaction Controller`.

If you are looking for only the total time of all the requests, then check the `Generate parent sample` checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could definitely do this in beanshell, start a timer and then calculate the end time. 
Also you might try something like the JC@gc package of extra plugins for something like responses over time.